# FreeBSD kernel image with built-in application

Tags: freebsd, netbsd, freebsd-ports

I have experienced creating a FreeBSD kernel image but is there a way to include an application, for example an SQlite database in the image? What I want to achieve is to package the application in the image build as one.

Comment: Sounds like you want something like Linux’ initramfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to include an application, for example, an SQlite database in the image?

Yes. It is. Mount your custom image or one of the publicly available [images](https://www.freebsd.org/where/) and use [*pkg*](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=&n=1) to install packages. Use the option `-r`. Quoting:

```
-r  <root directory>, --rootdir <root directory>
         pkg will install all packages within the specified <root
         directory>.
```

Notes:

- You can also update both kernel and userland on the mounted image. Use the variable *DESTDIR*. See the thread [Building FreeBSD to install or update in two DESTDIRs](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2012-May/240892.html).
- Don't forget to *umount* the image and destroy the [*mdconfig*](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?mdconfig(8)) *unit*.
- See the forum [mount an image file and change contents](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/mount-an-image-file-and-change-contents.21535/).
- Select the correct image. See the forum [Confusion with installers of ISO Disc Images on download FreeBSD!](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/confusion-with-installers-of-iso-disc-images-on-download-freebsd.55595/)

---

Example

- Create memory disk */dev/md0* from the image

```
shell> mdconfig -a -t vnode -u 0 -f FreeBSD-13.1-RELEASE-amd64.raw
```

- Show the partitions

```
shell> gpart show /dev/md0
=>       3  10552467  md0  GPT  (5.0G)
         3       123    1  freebsd-boot  (62K)
       126     66584    2  efi  (33M)
     66710   2097152    3  freebsd-swap  (1.0G)
   2163862   8388608    4  freebsd-ufs  (4.0G)
```

- Mount the partition to */mnt* and list the directory

```
shell> mount -t ufs /dev/md0p4 /mnt
shell> ll /mnt
total 176
drwxr-xr-x  18 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x  24 root  wheel  1024 Aug 21 16:05 ../
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel  1023 May 12 11:45 .cshrc
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   507 May 12 11:45 .profile
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel  6109 May 12 11:58 COPYRIGHT
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel  1024 May 12 11:55 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  wheel  1536 May 12 11:58 boot/
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:39 dev/
drwxr-xr-x  28 root  wheel  2048 May 12 11:59 etc/
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0 May 12 11:59 firstboot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  2048 May 12 11:55 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:55 libexec/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:39 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:39 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:39 net/
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:39 proc/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel  2560 May 12 11:55 rescue/
drwxr-x---   2 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:58 root/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel  3072 May 12 11:56 sbin/
drwxrwxrwt   2 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:39 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:39 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  24 root  wheel   512 May 12 11:39 var/
```

- Install the package *sqlite3* within the specified root directory */mnt*

```
shell> pkg -r /mnt install sqlite3
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
Fetching meta.conf: 100%    163 B   0.2kB/s    00:01    
Fetching packagesite.pkg: 100%    6 MiB   1.7MB/s    00:04    
Processing entries: 100%
FreeBSD repository update completed. 31759 packages processed.
All repositories are up to date.
The following 2 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

New packages to be INSTALLED:
    libedit: 3.1.20210910,1
    sqlite3: 3.39.0,1

Number of packages to be installed: 2

The process will require 6 MiB more space.
1 MiB to be downloaded.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
[1/2] Fetching sqlite3-3.39.0,1.pkg: 100%    1 MiB   1.4MB/s    00:01    
[2/2] Fetching libedit-3.1.20210910,1.pkg: 100%  136 KiB 138.9kB/s    00:01    
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
[1/2] Installing libedit-3.1.20210910,1...
[1/2] Extracting libedit-3.1.20210910,1: 100%
[2/2] Installing sqlite3-3.39.0,1...
[2/2] Extracting sqlite3-3.39.0,1: 100%
```

- Take a look at the installed files

```
shell> for file in `pkg -r /mnt info -l sqlite3 | grep /usr/local`; do ll /mnt/$file; done
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1727552 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/bin/sqldiff*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1960488 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/bin/sqlite3*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  613415 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/include/sqlite3.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  37310 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/include/sqlite3ext.h
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  19 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so@ -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  19 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0@ -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1750208 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  297 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  3596 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/man/man1/sqlite3.1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  55 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/share/licenses/sqlite3-3.39.0,1/LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  71 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/share/licenses/sqlite3-3.39.0,1/PD
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  180 Aug 11 03:12 /mnt//usr/local/share/licenses/sqlite3-3.39.0,1/catalog.mk
```

- Umount the image and destroy the vnode

```
shell> umount /mnt
shell> mdconfig -l
md0 
shell> mdconfig -d -u 0
shell> mdconfig -l
```

Comment: Hm, I’m not quite sure this answers the entirety of the question. The way I’m reading it, OP wants a single file that contains both the kernel and the image you propose to create.

Comment: Your answer make sense to me, I will try. Thanks for the details @Vladimir Botka!